# Выбрать элементы с data-*

Tags: jquery, html

Приветствую.
Столкнулся с задачкой: надо дивы с одинаковыми значениями data-order обернуть врапером, с уникальным id.
Вот html:

```
<div class="schedule-day">
  <div class="hour" data-order="0044">1</div>
  <div class="hour" data-order="0044">2</div>
  <div class="hour" data-order="0044">3</div>

  <div class="hour">4</div>
  <div class="hour">5</div>
  <div class="hour">6</div>

  <div class="hour" data-order="0045">7</div>
  <div class="hour" data-order="0045">8</div>
  <div class="hour" data-order="0045">9</div>
</div>
```

Вот js:

```
var holder = $('.schedule-day');
var blocks = holder.find('.hour');
var tempVal;
var tempContainer;

blocks.each(function(){
    var val = $(this).attr('data-order');
    if (val != tempVal){
        tempContainer = $('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
        holder.append(tempContainer);
        tempVal = val;
    }
    tempContainer.append($(this));
})
```

Если бы такая конструкция была одна, то все было бы замечательно, но блоков с `class="schedule-day"` может быть сколько угодно, и вот в этом-то и проблема.

[Пример на jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p89hkrrh/1/).

Comment: Как вам такой вариант для обработки любого количество блоков с внутренними элементами (без использования each): http://jsfiddle.net/p89hkrrh/2/ ? Вот только немного недоделал, тут ещё нужно добавить логику для объединения блоков с одинаковым data-order (нужно идти, позже при необходимости могу сделать).

Comment: @fenris, обернутые группы должны оставаться внутри родительских элементов с классом "schedule-day" или вынесены за его пределы с новой обёрткой "wrapper"?

Comment: @Deonis, они должны быть обернуты "wrapper" и остаться внутри родительских элементов с классом "schedule-day", т.е. вообще никуда не перемещаться, а только обернуться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вот?
http://jsfiddle.net/p89hkrrh/6/

В пределах одного ".schedule-day" оборачиваем ".wrapper"-ом сколь угодно элементов с уникальным с уникальным "data-order" и этому ".wrapper" - присваиваем уникальный  идентификатор.

Comment: Спасибо. Все круто.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, [проверяем такое решение](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/p89hkrrh/7/).

```
var holder = $('.schedule-day');

holder.each(function(i, el){
    $('[data-order]', el).each(function(i, div){
        var d = $(div).data('order'),
            group = $(div)
            .nextAll('div[data-order="' + d + '"]')
            .add(div)
            .wrapAll('<div class="wrapper" />');
        $(div).replaceAll(group);
    });
});
```

**UPD** Поспешил слегка... Так, насколько я понял, [будет правильней](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/p89hkrrh/8/)

```
var holder = $('.schedule-day');

holder.each(function(i, el){
    $('[data-order]', el).each(function(i, div){
        var d = $(div).data('order'),
            group = $(div)
            .nextAll('div[data-order="' + d + '"]')
            .add(div).filter(function(){
                return $(this).parent('.wrapper').length == 0;
            }).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper" >');
        group.replaceWith(group);
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, но подошел вариант из коммента выше.